# How to setup a php client Thrift 0.9.1 ...

Tags: php, namespaces, thrift

I'm trying to setup a php client for RPC with a HBase Thrift server but I'm getting some errors at the begining ... I've compilated the HBase.thrift file (with the 0.9.1 compiler) and I've put the 2 generated files like bellow (/ is the root of my project, I'm using apache server on ArchOS) :

- /include/Hbase.php
- /include/Types.php

I've included the lib folder of thrift0.9.1/lib/php/lib (composed of Thrift and sub folders) under / and so I've the following file system :

- /include/HBase.php

  - /Types.php
- /Thrift/Base

  - /ClassLoader
  - /Exception
  - /ext
  - ...

To be able to use my service (HBase.php) I've to load files so my code is the following :

```
<?php 
$GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = PHYSICAL_PATH;

 // Load up all the thrift stuff
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Transport/TTransport.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Transport/TSocket.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Protocol/TProtocol.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Transport/TBufferedTransport.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Type/TMessageType.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Factory/TStringFuncFactory.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/StringFunc/TStringFunc.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/StringFunc/Core.php';  
require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'].'Thrift/Type/TType.php';  
use Thrift\Protocol\TBinaryProtocol;  
use Thrift\Transport\TSocket;  
use Thrift\Transport\TSocketPool;  
use Thrift\Transport\TFramedTransport;  
use Thrift\Transport\TBufferedTransport; 

//hbase thrift
require_once ('Hbase.php');
require_once ('Types.php');
?>
```

When I'm charging the different files, I'm getting an error for this line --require_once ('Types.php');-- and the error is : Fatal error: Class 'Thrift\Exception\TException' not found in /var/www/html/POCThrift2/include/Types.php on line 1266

I understand it like : When I tried to include Types.php, the Thrift\Exception\TException namespace was not use (despite the use Thrift\Exception\TException; in the beginig of the Types file) but I don't know why I'm getting his error ... can you help me ? Does anyone has encountered this problem before ? Thx in advance, I'm stuuuck right now ...

Comment: The problem is apparently coming from the autoload ... The Types.php file is using namespaces but is not making include_once before ... If I add the include_once by hand it's working ! I'll try later to resolve this autoload, if you have any ideas on how to autoload classes don't hesitate, I'm just using an apache server (with php 5) and no frameworks (I'm just creating a POC)

Comment: I'd suggest to ask that question also on the mailing list and/or in the freenode channel.